# How can I make my powershell module import permanent?

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell

On an older Windows 8.1 machine, I have to use `Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck Storage` every time I want to use VHD related commands from Powershell. But unlike what the command seem to imply, it's not actually *importing* the module, but merely *loading* it. Because I need to run it every time I start pwsh.

**How can I make that module import stay permanent?**

---

**UPDATE:** 2020-01-26

From the [About Modules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7) page:

> Also, commands that use PowerShell providers do not automatically import a module. For example, if you use a command that requires the `WSMan: drive`, such as the `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` cmdlet, you might need to run the Import-Module cmdlet to import the `Microsoft.WSMan.Management` module that includes the `WSMan: drive`.
>
> You can still run the `Import-Module` command to import a module and use the `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` variable to enable, disable and configure automatic importing of modules. For more information, see ...

And from the [About Preferences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#psmoduleautoloadingpreference) page for `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference`:

> Enables and disables automatic importing of modules in the session. All is the default. Regardless of the variable's value, you can use Import-Module to import a module.
>
> Valid values are:
> **`All`** : Modules are imported automatically on first-use. To import a module, get or use any command in the module. For example, use Get-Command.
>
> **`ModuleQualified`** : Modules are imported automatically only when a user uses the module-qualified name of a command in the module. For example, if the user types MyModule\MyCommand, PowerShell imports the MyModule module.
>
> **`None`**: Automatic importing of modules is disabled in the session. To import a module, use the Import-Module cmdlet.

However, my `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Import-Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7)

> The Import-Module cmdlet adds one or more modules to the current session. The modules that you import must be installed on the local computer or a remote computer.

So it's not supposed to be a permanent change and the command also doesn't imply it. You could add the load command to your profile. If you didn't need to use `SkipEditionCheck` it also would probably work by just using tab completion and auto import/load.

See [about_Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) for information about profiles. Change the version to match the one you use.

Comment: That's interesting because when using on other shell versions on the same system the command *are* available, but there are no such imports in their startup profiles, AFAICT! So it must be done somewhere else...

Comment: Yes, because there is auto loading (starting with v3). But if you do have other shell versions available why would you pick one that is incompatible with the commands you would like to run? See [about_Modules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7).

Comment: I'm running different shells for different purposes on production machines. Notably PS 7.0+ for development & testing.

Comment: Seem that my `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` is empty... I wonder why?

Comment: I don*t know. But my assumption would still be that the issue stems from having to ignore compatibility to load the module. PowerShell probably doesn't look for commands in modules that are marked incompatible. The configuration variable seems to be empty for me as well.

Comment: A little late, but I just read:  *`The $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference variable does not exist by default. The default behavior when the variable isn't defined is the same as $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference = 'All'.`*

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the user profile script (that runs every time powershell starts) to run any commands you want including importing modules.

Located at
`C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` or through via the powershell `$Profile` variable.

Changes only apply to that user account on that computer, so don't forget that if you are developing scripts for others to use.